# Создать изображение на сервере?

Tags: php, python, node.js

У меня есть фоновая картинка и есть некие данные в json-формате. Я хочу создать изображение 1500*1500 с имеющимся у меня фоном и нанести на него текст из имеющегося json. Есть ли технологии, которые могли бы позволить реализовать такую фичу?

Answer (score 1):

В PHP есть встроенные библиотеки [GD](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.image.php) и [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php)

Answer (score 0):

canvas ? Создаешь холст нужного размера и засовываешь туда всё что тебе надо, хоть текст